# How do I pass in the correct parameters for a UDP socket's send function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp

I'm trying to respond to a request using two UDP sockets. The server acting socket is getting a no implicit conversion to string error. I've checked that all parameters are of the correct objects. Please help me.

```rb
require 'socket'


socket = UDPSocket.new()
socket.bind('0.0.0.0',6666)
loop do
  command,sender = socket.recvfrom(24)
  ip = sender[3]
  resp = system(command)
  #sender[1] is the port of the sender. I've not used udp but that might be wrong.
  socket.send(resp, 0, ip.to_s, sender[1]) #no implicit conversion of true into String
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.send`'s first argument should be a string. You have supplied the return value of `system(command)` [which is a boolean](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/system).

If you wish to capture the *output* of running a command, you should use backticks rather than `system`.

```
resp = `#{command.to_s}`
```